# Looking for trilogy of kids' books about geniuses living on an island

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I remember a trilogy of YA books I read as a kid, but I can't remember the name.  Here are a few details, maybe they'll strike a chord with someone here.

- They were written sometime in the 90s.
- It was about a group of geniuses who all moved to an island to work
  on something.  The protagonists were the children of the geniuses, and were even more brilliant than their parents.
- The protagonists made a supercomputer called either Sherlock or Watson.  Probably Sherlock, since it's supposed to be superbrilliant.  It had an accent, I think.  This supercomputer was sometimes referred to as the most powerful computer in the world.
- Either the first or second book had a big red robot on the cover.  Or maybe the cover was red and the robot wasn't.
- I think another book had a shark on the cover.  I think this cover was yellow-themed.
- One of the adults was a traitor or villain of some sort.  His (or her) identity was kept ambiguous for a while, and only revealed at the end of the third book.
- I remember one line about how their watches were powered by the heat from their skin, not batteries.  This was pretty weird at the time.
- It ended with their supercomputer somehow becoming sentient and helping save the day.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[The A.I. Gang by Bruce Coville](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671892495) :)

The first book is [Operation Sherlock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671892495), followed by [Robot Trouble](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671892525) and [Forever Begin](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451144546).

Amazon's description is

> When five brilliant but wacky kids get dragged to a deserted island by
>   their scientist parents, they decide to do what any self-respecting
>   kid geniuses would do under the circumstances: beat the adults at
>   their own game. The only problem is, before the gang can discover
>   whether Artificial Intelligence is an impossible dream of the solution
>   to mankind's problems, they'll have to save themselves from a
>   horrifying death trap -- and the entire island from destruction at the
>   hands of a mad bomber.

Comment: ... wow. I just looked him up on Wikipedia, and it turns out that Bruce Coville single-handedly wrote every book I read before I turned twelve.

Comment: I had no idea it was the same author as Jeremy Thatcher, Dragon Hatcher!